# iOS: Start uploading user location after request from server

Tags: ios, gps, notifications, push-notification, tracking

I need to achieve this: I have an app, which wants to keep track of location of family members. Since I don't want to keep the GPS running all the time, I was thinking I could just send a request from server, when some family member wants to know my location. 
But I ran into some problems: 
I can't use PUSH Notifications, because those need to be confirmed (tapped on) and only after that the app knows something happened. (This would not be great, since kids probably wouldn't tap the push notifications) 
The other option would be to keep the app running in the background, checking server for any news and if it found some request on server only then start the GPS tracking and upload coordinates to server. This sounds a bit better, but also battery draining. 
Did anyone already try this? Is there any better way to this problem? 
Thanks for any reactions! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think the only option for you left is run Location Services in background.

For this in Plist set for `Required background modes` to `App registers for location updates`. This will enable you to send location updates as you want.
But note that this will only work when application is running or in background, and it will not run when you application is closed. If user closes your application, then you can fire push notification if you done get any updates from device.

Also, note that you need to mention in description of your application, that Application uses location services which will drain your battery, otherwise your application will not be approved.

Hope this info helps you..

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem in our application. We followed the approach that keep listening to push notification port, whenever we receive any notification, then check if it's for our application and then react accordingly.

We can have listening to port on long time to save battery draining.
Sorry cannot share any of the code with you, but I hope this might be some help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample link from where you referred this?

Comment: I do not have any link available with me right now.Let me tell you some basics which won't harm me using `sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist", buffer, &lenth, 0, 0);` you can find out `inpcb structure`. then with the help of `ntohs(theInpcbStruct->imp_fport)` you can get the port.Compare this port with 5223 and 443.This are for listening.Once you know you have notification ask your server if it has any data for your application.

Sorry,I kinda explained a little wrong in answer.We listen 2 notification post n whenever we know that there is notification,we ask server through if it has any data.

Comment: This is quite interesting. If I may ask, how do you keep checking for those packets in background? Did you register your app as voip app to run in background? (I'm not very experienced in background tasks so excuse my lame questions :)) And lastly, do you think it would be possible to start location services after I check the server and see that i need to send location or do I need to keep location services alive the whole time and just send current info when needed? Thanks!